# Login not working... where is the error in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, user-defined-functions

This is the HTML with form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../htdocs/SpryAssets_index/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../htdocs/SpryAssets_index/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
            include ('includes/header.html')
        ?>
        <br /><br />
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p id="results"></p>
        <form action="login_ajax.php" method="post" id="login">
            <p id="emailP">Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><span class="errorMessage" id="emailError">Please enter your email address!</span></p>
            <p id="passwordP">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><span class="errorMessage" id="passwordError">Please enter your password!</span></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" /></p>
</form>
        <div class="footer">
        <?php
            include ('includes/footer.html')
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the handler login_ajax.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    function check_login($dbc, $email = 'email', $pass = 'pass') {
    $errors = array(); //Intialize the error array.
        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
        } else {
            $e = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }
        if (empty($pass)) {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
        } else {
            $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pass));
        }
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $q = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                echo 'CORRECT';
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'The email address and password entered do not match those on file.';
                echo 'INCORRECT';
            }               
        session_start();//START A SESSION HERE.
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $data['last_name'];    
        }
    }
check_login($dbc, $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
} else {
    echo 'INVALID_EMAIL';
}
} else {
echo 'INCOMPLETE';
}
?>
```

This is the Javascript that handles the echo login.js:

```
// Script 15.10 - login.js
// This script is included by login.php.
// This script handles and validates the form submission.
// This script then makes an Ajax request of login_ajax.php.

// Do something when the document is ready:
$(function() {

// Hide all error messages:
$('.errorMessage').hide();

// Assign an event handler to the form:
$('#login').submit(function() {

    // Initialize some variables:
    var email, password;

    // Validate the email address:
    if ($('#email').val().length >= 6) {

        // Get the email address:
        email = $('#email').val();

        // Clear an error, if one existed:
        $('#emailP').removeClass('error');

        // Hide the error message, if it was visible:
        $('#emailError').hide();

    } else { // Invalid email address!

        // Add an error class:
        $('#emailP').addClass('error');

        // Show the error message:
        $('#emailError').show();

    }

    // Validate the password:
    if ($('#password').val().length > 0) {
        password = $('#password').val();
        $('#passwordP').removeClass('error');
        $('#passwordError').hide();
    } else {
        $('#passwordP').addClass('error');
        $('#passwordError').show();
    }

    // If appropriate, perform the Ajax request:
    if (email && password) {

        // Create an object for the form data:
        var data = new Object();
        data.email = email;
        data.password = password;

        // Create an object of Ajax options:
        var options = new Object();

        // Establish each setting:
        options.data = data;
        options.dataType = 'text';
        options.type = 'get';
        options.success = function(response) {

            // Worked:
            if (response == 'CORRECT') {

                // Hide the form:
                $('#login').hide();

                // Show a message:
                $('#results').removeClass('error');
                $('#results').text('You are now logged in!');

            } else if (response == 'INCORRECT') {
                $('#results').text('The submitted credentials do not match those on file!');
                $('#results').addClass('error');
            } else if (response == 'INCOMPLETE') {
                $('#results').text('Please provide an email address and a password!');
                $('#results').addClass('error');
            } else if (response == 'INVALID_EMAIL') {                   
                $('#results').text('Please provide your email address!');
                $('#results').addClass('error');
            }

        }; // End of success.
        options.url = 'login_ajax.php';

        // Perform the request:
        $.ajax(options);

    } // End of email && password IF.

    // Return false to prevent an actual form submission:
    return false;

}); // End of form submission.

}); // End of document ready.
```

This form is returning an INCOMPLETE from the PHP handler which the Javascript is returning as "Please provide an email address and a password!".

Comment: What debugging have you done? I don't see any. You should at least be able to narrow it down to a snippet of code.

Comment: Remove the `isset` and the `@` for PHPs assistence. Notices and warnings are useful in such cases.

Comment: Can we see a HTML snippet of your form?

Comment: @mario When I take out the isset, it does nothing.

Comment: your function call `check_login();` have no parameters and you have not defined `$data[]` inside your function

Comment: If it says `INCOMPLETE`, either `$_POST['email']` or `$_POST['password']` is not set. `var_dump($_POST);` to find out what it looks like. Also, you call `check_login()` without parameters. I don't know why Mario says to remove the `isset`, unless he can explain why I'd ignore that...

Comment: You obviously aren't taking the advice from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984908/login-is-doing-nothing-where-is-the-error) very seriously. Time to throw out this book you're using and start fresh from some **recent** tutorials

Comment: @Phil, First, I have no intentions on taking advice from people that are only on here trolling and insulting people. It isn't necessary. Second, this code is not the book. If you had read that forum post, I was using segments from a cookbook, but all of this code is mine from what I know and built.

Comment: @Jetson324 Seems you deleted the comment where you explained your source material. Book / cookbook / whatever, the segments you've taken away from whatever you're reading are not good practice. Find some recent material (last 2 years should be ok, PHP 5.3 or later) and start fresh. Also, FYI I was not involved in the previous post at all. Don't know where you got that from

Comment: @Jetson324, Phil isn't trolling, you haven't bothered to grasp the basics of PHP, as you have very clearly shown in your question and your responses to a valid answer. You're also obstructive and offensive to people who are here to help others. You don't deserve help.

Comment: Can you please post up the html form that you are using?

Comment: @Phil, I deleted the forum post itself, and I just told you that this code is 100% mine. The practice is mine, not the books, and I don't know where the issue is. Also, I did not say that you were on the forum. If you interpreted that from what I said, it isn't what I meant. I deleted the forum because it became all about how I don't know PHP instead of addressing the problem.

Comment: @Nigel Angel. None of the answers that have been posted has solved the issue, nor has it gotten me to a solution on my own. The posts have become about how I do not know PHP. As for obstructive, I don't follow how I am being obstructive? As for offensive, I am not the one telling people that they "haven't bothered to grasp the basics of PHP" and "You don't deserve help".

Comment: @Jetson324 Just so I understand it, you have the form on 1 page, and then the script above is in a separate file login.php?

Comment: @NigelAngel like I said, the answer below is producing a syntax error. In dreamweaver, when I copied and pasted his answer into line 4, like he said to do, it says, "1/2 There is a syntax error on line 4. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error." When I run the code it does nothing.

Comment: @BecsCarter Yes, it is in another file and in the head of the html it calls login.js, which runs the operation.

Comment: login.js or login.php?

Comment: @NigelAngel you need to calm down sir. I am being absolutely calm with you and you seem to be unnecessarily agitated. "So what popnoodles posted earlier I'm guessing you've done this function check_login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']){ ..." was not right because as I stated it is producing a syntax error that I just described.

Comment: @BecsCarter <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: @BecsCarter That is what I put in the head of the HTML

Comment: Ok. Your form action is for login.php, so the login script in your question is form the login.php file yes?

Comment: @BecsCarter The form is being handled by login.php, but the php code is in login_ajax.php, which is a separate file. So right there is one issue. However, I don't understand why it is echoing INCOMPLETE from login_ajax.php when the value is never echoed.

Comment: Oh I'm getting confused sorry! So the php script above is not outputting any $_POST data when you use vardump? This will be because you are sending the post data to login.php which is then getting login_ajax.php to process it. There is no $_POST available by the time you reach the first isset() check. Which is why you are getting INCOMPLETE all the time

Comment: @Popnoodles I changed that line, however, it is still doing the same original issue where it is only echoing INCOMPLETE.

Comment: @Popnoodles but he says he keeps getting incomplete which means that it isnt even reaching the function call. Its failing the first if condition. Indicating that there is no post data available

Comment: @Popnoodles and I agree that function call is up the piss! Which will start to cause a new problem when his script gets that far

Comment: @BecsCarter that is exactly it! The first conditional is failing as if there is no data being entered even when there is data being entered. I wanted to solve problem #1 before I got to the call function. lmao!

Comment: The PHP code above is in a file called login_ajax.php. The form is being handled by login.php (which can't be right, should it be handled by login_ajax.php?), and the results are being handled by login.js depending on what is being echoed in the PHP. So when it echoes INCOMPLETE, the user sees, "Please provide an email address and a password."

Comment: You're going to have to show the code that actually sends POST data to your PHP script above (`login_ajax.php`). It sounds like you've got some JavaScript intercepting the form submission so you're going to have to add that to your question above (use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20985695/edit))

Comment: @Jetson324 You will need to show the code that sends your data to login_ajax.php as that is most likely where the problem. Depending what that is, will determine how you check the data in your first condition which keeps failing

Comment: @Jetson324, just a suggestion for the future... if you make it super clear right at the start your file structure, it will help us help you. Its only after I have been digging that you have said there are other files involved. That makes all the difference on how you handle data :-)

Comment: @BecsCarter I have updated it. Thanks, for the advice. I was trying to keep it simple, but I guess I made it a little too simple. LOL.

Comment: So what exactly do you think `options.type = 'get'` does in your `$.ajax` options? And once again, we come back to that book you're using - *PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites, Fourth Edition*. Throw it out, it's just plain bad

Comment: So now that you have changed your form action to login_ajax.php, what happens if you vardump?

Comment: Also, if you keep getting INCOMPLETE displayed on your screen, then your javascript file is not even working. If you want your JS file to do the processing etc, you will need to prevent the default form action from happening, then it will carry on with your JS processing

Comment: @Phil I actually forgot to update that when I changed the php from $_GET to $_POST. Keep in mind this is a login page. Someone told me I need to change that from $_GET to $_POST, even though from what I understand it is getting from the dbc.

Comment: @BecsCarter it still displays nothing.

Comment: @BecsCarter if I change the form handler to login_ajax then what happens is the options.url = 'login_ajax.php'; $.ajax(options); doesn't initialize, so the page doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm ok, I am just on my way home from work (diff timezones to you guys!). I'll log back in when I get home and carry on helping you out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres my suggestion for you. Hopefully this makes sense and works for you. Please try to understand what is happening rather than just copy and hope it works. Your form, on submit, gets sent to the JS file. This grabs the form values, uses JSON to send them to your php file which processes everything and returns a response, either true or false. If false, the js file will display your errors on screen and add classes etc. If true you can get it to redirector do whatever you want.

HTML form...

```
<h1>Login</h1>
        <p id="results"></p>    
<form action="login_ajax.php" method="post" id="login" onsubmit="jsquicksub(this); return false;>
                <p id="emailP">Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><span class="errorMessage" id="emailError">Please enter your email address!</span></p>
                <p id="passwordP">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><span class="errorMessage" id="passwordError">Please enter your password!</span></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" /></p>
    </form>
```

In your login.js

```
// hide the div where the error reporting gets displayed on load of the page
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#results').hide();
});    

var gb_ajaxbusy = false;

function jsquicksub(po_form) {

    if (gb_ajaxbusy)
        return false;

    gb_ajaxbusy = true;


    var lo_request = {};
    // go through each and every form element and assign to variable
    lo_request.e = $(po_form).find('#email').val();
    lo_request.p = $(po_form).find('#password').val();

    $(po_form).fadeTo(200, 0.3);

    $.getJSON('/login.php', lo_request, function(po_result) { // php form processing field

        gb_ajaxbusy = false;
        $(po_form).fadeTo(0, 1);

        if (!po_result.success) {
            $('#results').show();
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = po_result.content; 

// inserts errors in specified div. can use alert if wanted
// do your thing with adding classes etc if you want to
            return false;
        }
        // replace form with thankyou message/redirect somewhere or whatever you want to do

        // empty results element
        $('#results').hide();

    });

} // end jsquicksub()
```

Then in your login.php file ....

```
// function gets passed values after validation and returns a message to the user on screen - gets passed back to JS file which then returns stuff to the screen
function jsonreturn($pb_success, $ps_content = null) {

    $lo_result = (object) array('success'=>$pb_success, 'content'=>$ps_content);

    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode($lo_result);
    exit;

} // end jsonreturn()

    // these values are recieved from the javascript function
    $ps_email = isset($_GET['e'])? $_GET['e']: null;
    $ps_password = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p']: null;


    if(empty($ps_email) OR empty($ps_password)) {
         // run your check_login stuff in here
         // use jsonreturn(false, 'message') for error OR when everything is fine and you have set the session, use jsonreturn(true, 'complete');
    }
else {
    jsonreturn(false, 'Your error message in here which gets added to the id="results" p tag');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are new ways to code, faster and better ; you are programing not in a very good way, everything is mixed so it get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your php handler is testing for POSTed variables, but you've set the javascript to send by GET.